# How to draw this picture?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

[image]

Hello.

How can I get a picture like this? It's a part of a bubble sort algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any foundational work to draw this yourself? Can you show us? That would really help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to do such things on your own, you will realize how much more fun it is to work with Ti*k*Z (even marmots can do that! ;-) and not depend on others.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={inner sep=5pt,font=\large,
rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4, draw, anchor=center,
rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split part fill={gray!50,white}}] 
\node [my shape] (a) 
{2\nodepart{two}8\nodepart{three}6\nodepart{four}4}; 
\node [my shape,right=3cm of a] (b) 
{2\nodepart{two}6\nodepart{three}8\nodepart{four}4}; 
\node [my shape,below=2cm of a] (c) 
{2\nodepart{two}6\nodepart{three}8\nodepart{four}4}; 
\node [my shape,right=3cm of c] (d) 
{2\nodepart{two}4\nodepart{three}8\nodepart{four}6}; 
\draw[latex-latex] ([yshift=-2mm]a.two south) -- ++(0,-0.3) -| ([yshift=-2mm]a.three south);
\draw[latex-latex] ([yshift=-2mm]c.two south) -- ++(0,-0.3) -| ([yshift=-2mm]c.four south);
\draw[-latex] ([xshift=2mm]a.east) -- ([xshift=-2mm]b.west) node[midway,above,font=\itshape] {intercambio};
\draw[-latex] ([xshift=2mm]c.east) -- ([xshift=-2mm]d.west) node[midway,above,font=\itshape] {intercambio};
\node[below=1.2cm of c,font=\itshape] {Lista inicial};
\node[below=1.2cm of d,font=\itshape] {Lista resultante};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seriously, I think you should render all your answers in the form of a cookbook!

Comment: @Raaja As long as it is a vegetarian cookbook, I am fine with that. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much !! I've read the following PDF: https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf     but I haven't found an easy way to do it. There is something about nodes and matrices. I had seen matrices on page 337.

Comment: @Salvador Yes, you could also use matrices here. The answer is never unique. Yet I do not necessarily see an advantage using here matrices instead of `shapes.multipart`. Matrices make IMHO more sense if the object has more than one row. The problem with using a matrix for the shapes is that you'd need to work a tiny bit harder to get the vertical lines that separate the cells, but of course it can be done.

Comment: @marmot I'm an absolute beginner with Tikz ... Sorry.  (But thank you).

Comment: @marmot well we never know!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tabular`, `alignat`, `eqparbox` and node connections from `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, bigstrut, eqparbox}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \eqmakebox[L]{\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  \hline
\cellcolor{Gainsboro}\bigstrut 2 & \rnode{A}{8} & \rnode{B}{6} & 4 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}}
 & {}\xrightarrow{\quad\textit{intercambio}\quad}{}
 & \eqmakebox[R]{\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  \hline
\cellcolor{Gainsboro}\bigstrut 2 & 6 & 8 & 4 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}} \\[3ex]%
 & \eqmakebox[L]{\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
 \hline
\cellcolor{Gainsboro}\bigstrut 2 & \Rnode{C}{6} & 8 & \Rnode{D}{4} \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}}
 &{} \xrightarrow{\quad\textit{intercambio}\quad}{}
 & \eqmakebox[R]{\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
 \hline
\cellcolor{Gainsboro}\bigstrut 2 & 4 & 8 & 6 \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}} \\[3ex]%
 & \eqmakebox[L]{\textit{Lista inicial}} & & \eqmakebox[R]{\textit{Lista resultante}}
 \end{alignat*}
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=<->, arrowinset=0.12, angle=-90, arm=2.5mm, nodesep=8pt}
\ncbar{A}{B}
\ncbar{C}{D}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard. It's an alternative solution. I notice that you are all experts. I use tables in Latex in a very basic way.

Comment: You'll learn gradually when you'll meet specific problems, like all of us…